# Can't access .mdf file of database --- Permission Issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to access a `.mdf` file of my database but I can't access it due to permission reason.

In Visual Studio I selected ADO.NET Connectivity, and then selected 'Generate New Database'. I selected my database `.mdf` file but it generated warning that I can't access it...

Can anyone solve my problem?

Picture showing warning: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vNvD.png

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to add an mdf file from your c:\program files\

Do you want to add an mdf file for the sole use of your app?  If so move it to your App_Data folder of your application.

However, if you want to connect to a database running on an instance of SQL Server, then from the Entity Framework 'New Connection' window, click 'change' next to Data Source, and select Microsoft SQL Server.  Now browse to your server instance and select the required database.

Answer (score 0):

The mdf  file is belongs to a database that’s is current in use, just stop SQL Service or detach the database, and now it OK you can add the mdf file.